# Convert str to int in django template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates, date-conversion

I need to convert the a date day to int to compare with other value in the template.

Something like this:

**views.py**

```
def userEdit(request):
    userdata = user.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
    dic.update({'userdata':userdata, 'dayrange': range(1,32)})
    return render(request, 'my_app/userEdit.html', dic)
```

**my_app/userEdit.html**

```
<select name="day">
  {% for i in dayrange %}
    {% if i == userdata.birth_date|date:"d" %}
      <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
    {% else %}
      <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I need to convert userdata.birth_date|date:"d" to int and then compare with the "i" variable in the for loop. Please help

Comment: What type is the userdata.birth_date

Comment: `userdata.birth_date` will give you an object instance (either `datetime` or `date` or whatever you're using). `userdata.birth_date|date:"d"` will convert the date into a `str` instance for you. However, you need the actual day value, which is the `int` instance that you need. I agree with @Splatmistro answer.

Comment: Why thank you @DamodarDahal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the `add` filter with an argument of 0 to coerce it to an integer e.g.

```
{% if i == userdata.birth_date|date:"d"|add:0 %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
{% if i == userdata.birth_date.day %}
  <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I use this with the year and month. It works!

Comment: Yes, it work for day but also I used with month and year and It works too. Thank you